# the usage of 'twice more than…’

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

Can we say that her new mobile phone costs her twice more than the one she bought last year? Is there a problem with the grammer? Compare it with ‘twice as much as…',which one is better? Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not incorrect, in this context, 'twice more' would not be recommended. It is generally used when an event is repeated twice after a first occurrence (e.g., 'I knocked his door twice more [after knocking it a first time] in order to be sure he wasn't there').

The best way to say it would be either

> Her new mobile phone costs her twice as much as the one she bought last year.

or

> Her new mobile phone costs her twice the price of the one she bought last year.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with *twice more than*, but you have to be careful about what you're trying to say.

If the old phone cost $100, then the following would describe the cost of the new phone:

- Twice as much: $200. ($100 times two.)
- Twice ***more*** *than*: $300. ($100 plus twice that.)
  This expression is equivalent to *twice **again** as much*, which is also used.